# Is there a thing such as Cell ID?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am writing a Macro in Excel which is supposed to delete entire Rows, or add Rows, based on input.

Now the amount of rows to be deleted should be determined based on the amount of Rows which are already there, so say if I have 12 Rows and a cell nearby with a Sum amount of 3, I have used the Cell value so far to determine the amount of Rows to be removed.

```
|1(A1)| Title (B1)
|1(A2)| Title (B2)
|1(A3)| Title (B3)
|3(A4)| Sum   (B4)
```

Here is the code I am using(the removing part, haven't gotten further yet):

```
If CInt(TextBox2.Value) = Cells(4, 1) Then
    MsgBox ("Values are equal")
    ElseIf CInt(TextBox2.Value) < Cells(34, 2) Then
    a = Cells(4, 1) - CInt(TextBox2.Value)
    For i = 1 To a
        Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
End If
```

**The Problem** What I have realised with this is, that the Summation Cell which I use to determine the Amount of Rows to be deleted, will move if I delete a Row, so it will not be at position (4,1) (::A4::) anymore.

**My Question:** Is there a way to use the cell with an ID which would never
change, or dynamically change the addressed Value of the Cell ?

Thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: Not sure but I think you can name a range to something else so it will be addressed by that variable which will not be dependent on the address.

Comment: How do you know which rows to remove? i.e. taking your example, if there are 12 rows and you want to delete 3, how do you know which ones to delete?

Comment: you can use Excel Named Range http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html and then something like `a = [nameOfYourNamedRange] - TextBox2.Value`

Answer (score 2):

If you Set a reference to a cell and delete cells above so that the cell move up, the cell reference will be updated accordingly. See following example:

```
Function testCellRef()
    Dim c As Range, i As Long
    Set c = [A18]
    For i = 1 To 10
        Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        Debug.Print "Deleted row " & i & ", cell Address is now " & c.Address
    Next i
End Function
```

will display in the immediate window:

```
Deleted row 1, cell Address is now $A$17
Deleted row 2, cell Address is now $A$16
Deleted row 3, cell Address is now $A$15
Deleted row 4, cell Address is now $A$14
Deleted row 5, cell Address is now $A$13
Deleted row 6, cell Address is now $A$12
Deleted row 7, cell Address is now $A$11
Deleted row 8, cell Address is now $A$10
Deleted row 9, cell Address is now $A$9
Deleted row 10, cell Address is now $A$9
```

Note that the last iteration, the row that is deleted (row 10) is below the cell tracked and so the address doesn't change.

Note also that if you replace [A18] by [A17], you will delete the row with the tracked cell and then the reference will become invalid at the 9th iteration and generate an error at the `c.Address` call.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the row that contains the Sum formula each time by using something like this:

```
Columns("A").Find("=SUM", , xlFormulas, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Value
```

That will search column A, starting at the last row and working up and will return the value of the cell that contains "=SUM".  If you have more than one cell with that you may need to change the direction or go another route.

Another option would be adding a variable like the example below:

```
x = 0

If CInt(TextBox2.Value) = Cells(4 + x, 1) Then
    MsgBox ("Values are equal")
    ElseIf CInt(TextBox2.Value) < Cells(34 + x, 2) Then
    a = Cells(4 + x, 1) - CInt(TextBox2.Value)
    For i = 1 To a
        Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
        x = x - 1
    Next
End If
```

I assume you also need to change the cell you compare to in column B.  When adding a row, just use `x = x + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the rows you have to loop backwards, that way the row numbers you assume at the beginning of the loop will remain intact.